# Want to generate a computed column specification only the letters before the space

Tags: sql, sql-server

I would like to generate a computed column specification that will capture the letters before a space.

for example i have these codes

"FY120 FMC" I'd like this to be "FY120"

Thank You

Comment: Welcome to SO. Always add what you have tried so far. We can help from there

Answer (score 4):

If you want to this as `select` statement then you can do :

```
select t.*, left(col, charindex(' ', col + ' ')-1)
from table t;
```

EDIT :  If you want this as table column then use `alter` statement :

```
alter table table
    add col as left(col, charindex(' ', col + ' ')-1)
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
DECLARE @data nvarchar(100)='FY120 FMC'

SELECT @data, SUBSTRING(@data,1,CHARINDEX(' ',@data)) AS ReqFormat
```

Result

```
data        ReqFormat
---------------------
FY120 FMC     FY120
```

Answer (score 0):

your computed column specification should be

```
case when charindex(' ', col) > 0 then substring(col, 1, charindex(' ', dg_reference)) else col end
```

So alter your table with the specification

```
alter table yourtable
    add col as case when charindex(' ', col) > 0 then substring(col, 1, charindex(' ', dg_reference)) else col end
```

This caters for instances where there is no space as well
Hope it helps